# Firebase: Update model from background message

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

How would I implement a new state of my model when my app receives a message with a data object from our server while in the background? `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage()` is working and I can see the data sent from the server but I can't figure out how to update the model with this new data. Assigning it to a variable works but reading this variable later returns null. I'm also using GetIt but can't call it when the app is in the background.
All the tutorials just show how to receive the data (and just print it into console) but none show how to actually use it when the app is in the background.

Edit: I've checked multiple sources, which describe cloud messaging, for example https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/. Most of them just describe how to receive the message. Example:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}
```

I've got this far. My message from the server contains a data object, which has the required model values (for example: `"newBalance" : 100.00`). But how do I update my model in my app with this new data while it is in the background? I don't seem to have access to it (as described above the assigned variable later returns null).

Comment: Please provide enough code and link (of tutorial you have refer) so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After almost a week of trying I think I found a workaround for my problem. Using the `hive` package the app writes the new data to the local database. However, calling `Hive.initFlutter()` was not working, while the app was in the background. So I wrote the path to the directory `(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path` into `SharedPreferences` in my `main()` method. Then, when the app receives a message while in the background, I call

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  SharedPreferencesAndroid.registerWith();
} else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  SharedPreferencesIOS.registerWith();
}
```

(from packages `shared_preferences_android` and `shared_preferences_ios`) and afterwards I can retreive the path `var dir = (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).getString("keyForDir");` for Hive. Using `Hive.init(dir)` I'm able to open the box to write my data there (`box.close()` afterwards). Finally I can read the data from Hive when the app is in the foreground again (don't forget `box.close()` afterwards).

Phew, what a bad solution but it's the only one working for me. Some other people on the internet seem to have the same problem (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98473) and some other solutions worked for them but not for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited, as the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage) says:

> Since the handler runs in its own isolate outside your applications context, it is not possible to update application state or execute any UI impacting logic. You can, however, perform logic such as HTTP requests, perform IO operations (e.g. updating local storage), communicate with other plugins etc.

For example you can use [Shared preferences plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save the received data from your background message handler like:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    final sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPrefs.setString('data', <YOUR DATA FROM MESSAGE>);
}
```

Since your application is in the background at this time, you need to fetch this value after it is resumed. Check for a complete example [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html), but basically you need something like this in your main widget:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    final sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final data = sharedPrefs.getString('data');
    print('Found in SharedPrefs: $data');
  }
}
```

After this you can find a way to update anything you need, already within your application's context.

Comment: Thanks. However, when I call `await SharedPreferences.getInstance()` while the app is in the background, the following exception is thrown: `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)`

Comment: @AlexP It means that the shared preferences plugin is not available. Have you added the package to `pubspec.yaml`, ran `flutter pub get` and rebuilt the app? If yes, try `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and build again.

Comment: Yes, I'm already using it in other parts of the app. When I call the same method when receiving a message while the app is in the foreground, everything works fine.

Comment: @AlexP Strange, I use exactly this code and it works for me. I just tested it with real iPhone device. I also call other plugins from background message handler without any problems.

Comment: @AlexP You can try to use a top level global variable in the dart file where your background message handler is. I have not tried it and it is not a very nice solution but might worth a try.

Comment: I've tried top level variables too but when I access them later when the app goes into the foreground, they always return null. If the handler runs in an isolate, it probably won't be able to save the value to a variable of the app. I'm running the app on Android.

Comment: I think I found a working solution for me. Check the accepted answer in case you are interested. Thank you for your answer and comments too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Firestore` to update the App, the `SharedPreferences` didn't work

In `onBackgroundMessage` I'm doing the following

```
await Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) async {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('background').doc(dt1).set({
    "date": dt1,
    // add fields to the Doc
  }).then((value) async {
    FirebaseService.localNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0,
      "$title",
      "$body",
      FirebaseService.platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: "$payload",
    )
  });
```